# UISplitViewController template can't contain a Group'd UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a simple iPad application based on the UISplitViewController template. I'd like the Root View Controller - to have the 'Group' style on it instead of 'Plain'. Unfortunately, the UITableView associated with the controller is nowhere to be found. In other words, there are not properties for me to change.

Has anyone else succeeded at this?

Thanks,
-Luther

Comment: Since you have a `tableView` , did you not add a `UITableViewController` in one of the views of your SplitViewController ?

Comment: "I have created a simple iPad application based on the UISplitViewController template" ... that template creates an application with two UITableViewControllers - a Root and a Detail. Create a new iPad app and you'll see what I'm referring to. I don't add any controllers as the template already has them in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a cleaner way to do this but put this in the root view class:

```
-(void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I agree - there must be a cleaner way - something seems amiss in the prebuilt XIB file. But that said, your suggestion is brilliant! Works perfectly. One note, "self.tableView" is a (nonatomic,retain) property and as such, your code has a memory leak since 'alloc' will add a 'retain' count and then assigning to self.tableView will add another 'retain' count. If you use the above method, be sure to release the tableView at least once before you leave this method.